# CKAN extensions overwrite each other, what is the correct order?

Tags: ckan

When multiple CKAN extensions are installed, they seem to overwrite each other. `e.g.ckan.plugins = pulgin1, plugin2, plugin3`

If both plugin1 and plugin2 modify the look and feel(jinja tempaltes) of a page, it seems plugin1 takes precedence over plugin2. Is this always like this?

What about functionalities(functions, etc.)? Did not find the code relate to this or documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to **templates**, plugins listed to the left take precedence over those listed further to the right. In your example, if all three plugins provide the same template than that of `plugin1` will be used.

However, this does not mean that the template changes by the other plugins are completely lost: when implementing a template, a plugin can decide to *extend* the existing template using the [`ckan_extends`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/theming/templates.html#extending-templates-with-ckan-extends) syntax.

If each of the plugins in your example uses `ckan_extends` on the same template, then `plugin3` extends CKAN's base version of that template, `plugin2` extends that of `plugin3`, and finally `plugin1` extends that of `plugin2`. If one of the plugins doesn't use `ckan_extends` then that chain is broken.

**In the other cases**, plugins are usually called in the order they are listed (from left to right). For example, if both `plugin1` and `plugin2` implement the [`IMiddleware`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IMiddleware) interface then `plugin1.make_middleware` is called first and its result is passed to `plugin2.make_middleware`.

This also means that plugins listed to the left override those to the right when they use the same name for a resource view type, template helper, etc. See [the section on avoiding name clashes](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/best-practices.html#avoid-name-clashes) in the CKAN documentation for more information.

For **action functions** defined via [`IActions`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IActions), you can use the [`ckan.plugins.toolkit.chained_action`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IActions.get_actions) decorator to extend existing action functions instead of replacing them (similar to template inheritance).  The same holds for **auth functions** defined via [`IAuthFunctions`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthFunctions), where you can use the [`ckan.plugins.toolkit.chained_auth_function`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthFunctions.get_auth_functions) decorator.

Comment: TY, Florian! I did not find related info in the documentation. Did I just miss it? Your answer provides valuable info that shall be recorded somewhere. If it is not in the documentation yet, I volunteer to put it in.

Comment: I don't think it's explicitly mentioned in the docs, yet. Feel free to submit a PR!

Comment: Found this note in the documentation
```
The order of the plugin names in the configuration file influences the order that CKAN will load the plugins in. As long as each plugin class is implemented in a separate Python module (i.e. in a separate Python source code file), the plugins will be loaded in the order given in the configuration file.
...
templates found in template directories added earlier will override templates in template directories added later.
```
 https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-plugins

Comment: So, "ckan_extends" basically means "keep resolving this and come back with the result".